# How to set postgres query execution timeout from application level?

Tags: postgresql, laravel, pdo, timeout

I am creating a web application in php(using Laravel), I would like to set a query execution timeout to PostgreSQL but I don't have access to server configuration, so is there any other way set query execution timeout through application level?

Thank you

Comment: Use a DB-level or user-level configuration:
1. `ALTER DATABASE postgres SET statement_timeout='1s';`
2. `ALTER ROLE postgres SET statement_timeout='1s';`

Answer (score 17):

Simply send the following statement:

```
set statement_timeout TO 100;
```

Postgresql will then cancel all queries exceeding 100ms.

Comment: thank you, for you quick response, is there any PDO configuration or is there any way to run an init query in laravel?